# Scripts and css not loaded in intranet app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, intranet

I have an MVC5 intranet app with windows authentication. Mine is a home computer not on the network/domain. I run the app from VS2013. When I log in to the app as current Logged In user, everything works fine.

I have created few other administrator accounts on my machine. When i log in to the app with one of them (for testing purposes), the scripts and css does not load.

I tried setting allow users="*" under authorization. But it doesn't work.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Ok. I solved this. There were errors in the actions i had used and hence not loaded properly. Changed them to HTMLActionLinks and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were errors in the actions i had used and hence not loaded properly. Changed them to HTMLActionLinks and it worked perfect for all scenarios virtual directories and website.